# How to add a Area-City associated select list in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Like this：

When you select a state, the second  will list all city of the state for choose.

Excuse my writing. My native language is not English

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for that. Implement a view that, given a state, return in json all cities in that state. Then on template use jquery in on change event of state combo to call that view and on success fill the other combo. It's harder to explain than implement.

Excuse my writting. I'm on mobile.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't quite understand.